# Get user information from a form even if the user does not "submit" the form

Tags: wordpress

One of our competitors is able to save the user information filled on their website even if the user hasnt "submit"ed the form. I want to understand how they are doing it. We are using wordpress on our website.
Thanks in advance!

I know WPforms offer this on their premium plan. I am thinking if this can be done without a premium plan.
More details here: https://wpforms.com/docs/how-to-install-and-use-form-abandonment-with-wpforms/

Comment: It says on the page you linked "In WPForms, there are 2 specific events that will trigger form abandonment: When the user moves their mouse outside of the browser’s viewport or When the user clicks on a link on the page." You could create similar event listeners with JavaScript, but how you would capture the information is up to you, whether saving to a database or otherwise.